# HP EliteDesk 600 turns of after releasing power on button

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, power

I have an EliteDesk 600.
The power switch on the front refuses to stay connected.  Depress it and the computer starts; release it and it switches off.
I have replaced the switch and this makes no difference.
Can anyone suggest what the problem may be that is causing this?

Comment: Please [edit] the title to summarize the question. Success!

Answer (score 3):

ATX-format PCs haven't had a front power *switch* since ~1995. They only have a power-on [**button**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_switch) which just triggers the power supply startup, and it is **normal** that it disconnects as soon as you release it. The PSU only needs to receive the "Power on" signal for a moment, then it continues running on its own.

This means that in your case, it is most likely the power supply unit which decides to turn itself off. It might be underpowered to handle fancy GPUs or large numbers of HDDs, or it might be simply faulty, but in either case you need to test the PSU first.

Comment: Yeah - and although the power button might make a click, as if it's being '*toggled*' on/off like old power switches, it's a fake clicking, and is only there to give you the impression. (It merely completes a circuit and the motherboard + O/S decide what to do as a result - power on / Suspend / hard off(4sec) etc). I would still check all the pins from power/reset are plugged into the correct locations on the motherboard. I guess if it's an older computer the way round they are might have an effect?

Comment: What I meant was it's not toggling into an '*on*' (depressed) position like old PCs used to (Although some really old ones had other things going on like a knob which combined the *on* switch with the pc speaker volume control - along with a lock! >.<). My current PC case actually completes the circuit before the click, so you can actually gently press and release without ever clicking ¬_¬ Not sure if that's scary now I've read your comment about sparks etc

Answer (score 2):

The switch is just a button that activates a circuit in the power supply. So the power supply is not staying on because it has a hardware issue or there is a problem external to the power supply.

How old is the machine? You need to get it serviced and to determine whether that is economical.